# How to add an image tooltip annotation in hidden mode using the LaTeX pdfcomment module?

Tags: pdf, pdfcomment, button

Using the `pdfcomment` package to create an interactive tooltip when hovering over an image can be created with:

```
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\pdftooltip{\includegraphics{img.png}}{This is the ALT text}
```

However this causes interference with my downstream PDF processor which adds another annotation onto this area. The tooltip catches mouse events and prevents expected operation.

If I use the `[disable]` option, the tooltip appears to be hidden, but actually the entire tooltip annotation object is absent from the PDF content stream.

Q: How can I use the `pdftooltip`, but set it to the 'hidden' state please?

I need it to be present in the PDF, but inactive and not catching any mouse events.

Comment: What is the use of a tooltip that does nothing? What are you trying to achieve? Have you seen the todonotes package?

Comment: Keks, this hidden mode is needed for the purposes of a down-stream PDF consuming process, not what it looks like to a viewer. The consuming process identifies the rectangle layout of the tooltip object, and it's text value. Then it overlays a 3D annotation at the same position. Without the hidden mode, the tooltip object grabs the left mouse events and breaks the interaction in the 3D annotation. The work-flow is described at: https://www.pdf3d.com/latex-3d-pdf-placeholder-method/ along with sample test files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick solution to your problem.

I have put together a modified pdfcomment.sty file, called [pdfcomment1.sty](https://drive.google.com/open?id=150sX4rfEJ7dgoW_a6FREpEAZi4apRO7W). It has a new function `pdftooltiphid`, which produces tooltips in the same way as the original `pdftooltip`, but sets them to 'hidden'. You can call this function in the regular way:

```
\pdftooltiphid{\includegraphics{img.png}}{This is the ALT text}
```

In order to use the new pdfcomment1.sty file, I suggest you do the following:

1. Locate your pdfcomment.sty file and rename it to 'pdfcomment_OLD.sty'. If you are wondering where to put the .sty file, or have trouble finding your other .sty files, take a look at this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te). And if you are using an online editor, such as Overleaf, see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_.cls,_.sty,_.bst_files,_and_I_want_to_put_them_in_a_folder_to_keep_my_project_uncluttered._But_my_project_is_not_finding_them_to_compile_correctly).
2. Rename the new pdfcomment1.sty file to 'pdfcomment.sty' and move it in the place of the old pdfcomment.sty.
3. Restart your LaTeX editor.

That's it--you should now be able to use `pdftooltiphid` to create tooltips that are hidden by default.

The modified package does not change the functionality of the old `pdfcomment`, apart from adding the new function `pdftooltiphid`. However, it would be good to notify [Josef Kleber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3190/josef), the author of `pdfcomment`, who would probably want to improve upon my quick solution.

Comment: Thank you Anton, your method works very well! I have checked the resulting PDF structure in Adobe Acrobat Pro Preflight analysis, verified the hidden mode is set as needed.